# $f'$ exists for a function of bounded variation

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, bounded-variation

If $f \in BV[a, b]$, show that $f'$ exists and is integrable.

My Attempt : I know that for any $f \in BV[a, b]$, we can write it as difference of two monotonic increasing functions and monotonic increasing functions are differentiable. But not sure if this is rigorous and correct.

Comment: Monotonic increasing functions are differentiable??consider the greatest integer function or floor function..is it differentiable??

Comment: @Upstart I believe the OP forgot the (quite crucial) words "almost everywhere."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is correct. Moreover since for a non decreasing function $g$ one has $\int_{[a:b]} g' d\lambda\leq g(b)-g(a)$ you obtain that $\int |f'| d\lambda \leq V(f)$ where $V(f)$ is the total variation of $f$. So its derivative is indeed integrable.

Note that the inequality can be strict : think of the cantor function.

Comment: You mean, the argument given by the OP implies differentiability *almost everywhere*?

Comment: Yes, of course. A monotonic function is only differentiable **almost everywhere**.